# Claims-based auth with ADFS 2.0 is missing _trust virtual directory

Tags: adfs, claims, virtual-directory

I am setting up claims-based authentication for SharePoint 2010 with AD FS 2.0 (following instructions [Configuring Claims Based Authentication for SharePoint with AD FS 2.0](http://shannonbray.wordpress.com/2010/05/29/configuring-claims-based-authentication-for-sharepoint-with-ad-fs-2-0/)

I've a claims-aware web application. However if I open IIS and explore the virtual directories, I can see _app_bin, _vti_pvt, etc but _trust is missing.

How do I enable the _trust virtual directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the comments in the article you are using http://shannonbray.wordpress.com/2010/05/29/configuring-claims-based-authentication-for-sharepoint-with-ad-fs-2-0/ 
There you have explanations for what you need to do if it is not created.